# Classic ASP session and Web Garden (multiple workers)

Tags: session, asp-classic, iis-6, session-state, worker-process

We are having issues with IIS6 slowdowns when using more than 1.2GB of RAM in a single worker and would like to use more workers. However looks like ASP sessions are made by worker and when the browser accesses some page through another worker it losts the ASP session.

Do you have some tips on how to solve this problem?

We are considering to use some other way to manage session separately from IIS (not database, maybe memcache?). Do you recomend something?

Note.: The application is full of legacy code and we need to avoid big changes in code.

Comment: Do you use any inprocess COM components that are 32 bit only components?  (Note ADODB has 64 bit versions).

Comment: Yes. A lot.

Update: We are evaluating ASPSession component from ADC Cure (http://www.nieropwebconsult.nl/asp_session_manager.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a similar scenario with a legacy app in the past and ended up writing a simple component to serialize the ASP Session object to & from the database.

Comment: I solved this a few weeks after I sent this question here by buying the ADC Cure ISP Session component and it makes the same as your component. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a central session store for classic ASP in the past using Redis as a storage layer. The code is freely downloadable at https://gitlab.com/erik4/classic-asp-book-examples

It uses a redis ActiveX/COM component, available [here](https://gitlab.com/erik4/redis-com-client).
Using a central session store using Redis will allow you to use as many worker processes as needed.

If you want a detailed explanation of the implemantation, there's an accompanying book, but the example code should work out of the box.