# Is there a trick to using Classic ASP session variables in an AWS load-balnced environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vbscript, asp-classic, session-variables, amazon-elb

I have an AWS, load-balanced, EC2 environment running a legacy ASP website. The application uses session variables to manage user login state.

The problem is, it doesn't always work when the environment scales to 2 or more instances. It's hit and miss and sometimes the variables don't exist after they are declared. Am I missing something for this type of environment?

When, there is only one EC2 instance. No trouble. More, and the session variable doesn't always establish.

```
Session("loggedin")=true
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Classic ASP session and Web Garden (multiple workers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268102/classic-asp-session-and-web-garden-multiple-workers)

Comment: Classic ASP `Session` was never designed to work as a Web Garden but that doesn’t mean you can’t implement something to serialize / deserialize the session state from a persistent data store. You could just store an `id` in a browser cookie that corresponds to data in your data store and drop the in-memory `Session` object altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're storing user session "in process" meaning it's stored in the memory of the server running your application, you need to enable "sticky sessions" on your load balancer so that each user is tied to that particular server. Otherwise you run into the issue you're seeing where the load balancer is sending traffic to a different server that may or may not have the session data you're looking for.
*(this is a bad idea so don't do this but this will solve your problem)*

The proper way to handle session, as sticky sessions doesn't scale properly, is to use a separate service or data store to handle user session data. You can store user session in Elasticache or DynamoDB for example and therefore session will be read outside of your EC2 instances and you can continue to add (or remove) new EC2 instances with no issues. You can also use a database server to handle your session information as well. The key is to not handle session data on the actual EC2 instance.

Check this out: [Using DynamoDB with Session](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-session-net-sdk.html)